# Creating a function with non-numeric values in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have written some code to calculate the winrate of a country in a dataset containing footballmatches, it looks like this:

```
netherlands_won = filter(yrs_60_till_now, home_team == 'Netherlands' & difference > 0 | away_team == 'Netherlands' & difference < 0)
netherlands_matches = filter(yrs_60_till_now, home_team == 'Netherlands' | away_team == 'Netherlands')
winrate_netherlands = (nrow(netherlands_won) / nrow(netherlands_matches))
```

This works perfectly, but I want to do this automatically for all other countries as well. I have tried some stuff out with functions and loops but none of it seems to work. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I made up some similar data:

```
tmp <- expand.grid(
  home_team = letters[1:6], 
  away_team = letters[1:6]
)
tmp <- tmp %>% 
  filter(home_team != away_team) %>% 
  mutate(difference = round(runif(n(), -3,3)))
head(tmp)
#   home_team away_team difference
# 1         b         a       -2.3
# 2         c         a        0.1
# 3         d         a        1.7
# 4         e         a       -0.2
# 5         f         a       -0.2
# 6         a         b        2.6
```

Then, you could write a function that would calculate the winrate:

```
winrate <- function(data, team){
  won = filter(data, home_team == team & difference > 0 | away_team == team & difference < 0)
  matches = filter(data, home_team == team | away_team == team)
  winrate = (nrow(won) / nrow(matches))
  winrate
}
```

Then, just call the function on your data for the desired team:

```
> winrate(tmp, 'a')
[1] 0.5
> winrate(tmp, 'b')
[1] 0.6
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!